# Why this $emit event is not working between component and parent in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, dropdown

Playing with an API and building a simple dropdown selector in Vue, I am stuck as of why events of a component do not reach the parent. I have looked on the documentation, with no success. I have tried both this.$emit and this.$parent.$emit with no success

Code sample here:
https://jsfiddle.net/behyfnxw/

The point is that method "updated" in the parent is never called when selecting a university from the dropdown menu.
Pretty new to Vue and frontend, any feedback is more than welcome. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <div id="app">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">
                <entity-selector :items="univs" :value="u0"></entity-selector>
                <entity-selector :items="deps" :value="d0"></entity-selector>
                <entity-selector :items="courses" :value="c0"></entity-selector>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    Vue.component('entity-selector', {
    props: ['items', 'value'],
    data: function () {
        return {
            selected: "u0",
        }
    },
    created: function () {
        console.log("entity selector created just now!");
    },
    mounted: function () {
        console.log("mounted");
        this.selected = this.value;
    },
    watch: {
        selected: function (newValue) {
            console.log("watch!", newValue);
            this.selected = newValue;

            console.log("to send event");
            this.$emit("updated");
            console.log("sent event");
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updated: function () {
            console.log("selected item:", this.selected);
            this.$emit("updated", "univ", this.selected);
            console.log("selected item:", this.selected);
        },
    }, 
    template:`
                <p class="col-xs-12">
                    <select class="form-control" @click="updated" v-model="selected" v-cloak>
                        <option v-for="item in items" :value="item.id">{{item.fullname}}</option>
                    </select>
                </p> 
            `
});</script>
    <script>
        var vm = new Vue({ 
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                u0: "u0",
                d0: "d0",
                c0: "c0",
                default_univ: {"id": "u0", "fullname": 'choose univ', "total": 0},
                default_dep: {"id": "d0", "fullname": 'choose dep', "total": 0},
                default_course: {"id": "c0", "fullname": 'choose course', "total": 0},
                univs: [{"id": "u0", "fullname": 'choose univ', "total": 0}],
                deps: [{"id": "d0", "fullname": 'choose dep', "total": 0}],
                courses: [{"id": "c0", "fullname": 'choose course', "total": 0}],
            }, 
            created: function () {
                console.log("main vue created just now!");
                this.fetch_entities("gr", 1);
            },        
            methods: {
                fetch_entities: function (parent, filetypeid) {
                    var main_endpoint = "https://api.trelosfoititis.gr/v1"; 
                    var url = main_endpoint + "/list?parentid=" + parent + "&filetypeid=" + filetypeid;
                    var self = this;
                    axios.get(url)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            self.fetched(parent, filetypeid, response.data.response.data);
                        });
                },
                updated: function (entity_type, entity_id){
                    console.log("updated!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", entity_type, entity_id);
                },
                fetched: function (parent, filetypeid, results){
                    console.log("fetched", parent, filetypeid);
                    if(parent == "gr"){
                        this.univs = (results.length > 0) ? [].concat([this.default_univ], results) : [this.default_univ];
                    }
                    
                },
            }
        })
    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to add the "@updated" ```<entity-selector :items="univs" :value="u0" @updated="updated">```

Comment: Damn, I knew it would be something simple, it's too late here I need to go for sleep, thank you!